# Is there any way to create a smooth scrolling in ionic web app?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, web-applications, frameworks, ionic-view

I have created a website using ionic framework.Everything is fine except the scrolling part.Since ionic framework is created for mobile apps the scrolling is smooth when I swipe the page.But when I scroll through the page using the mouse the transformation of the page is so slow that I have to scroll for a long time to reach the end.Is there any way to make the page scrolling smooth in the browser?

**Things I have noticed**

1. The scrolling is smooth when I have changed the view to mobile view
2. If I returned to normal view after the mobile view the scrolling works fine
3. If I refreshed the page from normal view, the smooth scrolling is gone

**Additional classes added to body and ion-nav-view in above situations**

1. The scrolling is smooth when I have changed the view to mobile view

   body : class="*grade-a platform-browser platform-android platform-android6 platform-android6_0 platform-ready*"

   ion-nav-view : nav-view-transition="*android*" nav-view-direction="*none*" class="*view-container*"
2. If I returned to normal view after the mobile view the scrolling works fine

   body : class="*grade-a platform-browser platform-android platform-android6 platform-android6_0 platform-ready*"

   ion-nav-view : nav-view-transition="*android*" nav-view-direction="*none*" class="*view-container*"
3. If I refreshed the page from normal view, the smooth scrolling is gone

   body : class="*grade-a platform-browser platform-win32 platform-ready*"

   ion-nav-view : nav-view-transition="*ios*" nav-view-direction="*none*" class="*view-container*"

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/Y71E3q/

Answer (score 2):

The scrolling became smooth when I have changed the ion-content to `<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" class="has-header">`

Answer (score 0):

This plugin helped me to achieve smooth scroll on some views: https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine#installation-instructions

Source I have googled:
http://blog.ionic.io/cordova-ios-performance-improvements-drop-in-speed-with-wkwebview/